# Best preposition choice

Tags: prepositions

> The playlist was played with the songs sung by the popular singers.

> The playlist was played in the songs sung by the popular singers.

Which preposition would be better in these sentences in or with?

Answer (score 1):

The first example feels a bit convoluted, but is generally correct. The second example is plainly wrong ;)

Let's start with the second example:

> <s>The playlist was played in the songs sung by popular singers.</s>

would mean that the playlist was played *in* the songs, like for example a band is playing *in* the concert hall. That just doesn't work ;)

On the other hand

> The playlist was played with the songs sung by the popular singers.

would technically mean that the playlist was played by using the songs of popular singers, like using a tool. While the sentence is grammatically correct, you would probably just say something like

> They played a list of songs by popular singers.

Some side notes:

- It's often considered good style not to repeat words or similar words in short order. So if you're already use "to play" in the sentence, maybe don't use "playlist", but just "list". If you're already using "songs", don't use "to sing", but maybe "to perform" (or no verb at all, like in the example above). Same for "singers", which could be replaced with "artists" or "performers", and so forth. Of course, if you specifically mean "singers" and not the more general "performers", for example, you sometimes can't help it.
- You don't have to use the definite article all the time. If you don't want to refer to some specific "the songs by popular artists", just "songs by popular artists" is completely fine. That would refer to some songs that are from popular artists, but not to any specific group of songs. Of course, if you *want* to refer to specific songs, specific artists and so forth, you use the definite article.
- It's also considered good style to use the passive voice only when there's a reason to use it. So, instead of "the playlist was played", maybe just use "They played the playlist".

Comment: I agree with most of this, but surely a playlist _is_ a series of songs or music tracks, so it would make more sense to say "The playlist _consisted of_ songs by popular artists"?

Comment: @KateBunting This would be another alternative, depending on the context. If we're talking about a playlist in the technical sense, maybe in a media player, just "list" might be too broad. On the other hand, the playlist can consist of any number of songs without ever being played ;) But the example sentence refer to the songs, or the list, being played. So, depending on the details of the situation, there are a lot of possible ways to phrase this.

Answer (score -1):

> The playlist was played with the songs sung by the popular singers.

This preposition is correct since *with* is a kind of a word accompanied by another term. While *in* is usually used for words referring to either things inside something, or a date( for example, 1952 and 2012), movements made, etc.

Also, if you read both sentences the 1st example sounds more natural and is grammatically correct rather than the 2nd one.

Comment: Sorry, but using "in" in this case is just plainly wrong (see my answer).

Comment: I've read it, uh. Did I mention **in** was correct though?

Comment: Ah, maybe I understood "the first example sounds more natural" wrong. It sounded to me like you thought that the second example was maybe less natural but basically correct (which it isn't).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the wrong in your first sentence? ;-; I didn't even say it was correct in my answer. I provided the answer, simply saying the 2nd example wasn't correct.

Comment: You said "Also, if you read both sentences the 1st example sounds more natural". I seem to have understood that incorrectly.

Comment: I'll just explain if you don't understand. What I mean by that sentence is the 1st sentence being correct, but I didn't mention the 2nd example to be right. I mean, if you read the 2nd example, you yourself would have known.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130413/discussion-between-sorryimdumb-and-henning-kockerbeck).

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to click that. I'm new here, ok ;-;